# Difference between netstat and ss and how to convert commands?

Tags: networking, netstat

what's the equivalent using ss command ?

```
netstat -antp
netstat -lntp
```

what's the difference if we use  ss with no hyphen and with  ss -a ?
what does this command do for us  ss -antlp ?

Comment: These questions seem easily answered on the manpage.  Is there something on the manpage that you don't understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made a [comparison table (in Google Docs)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_iZPZv6j2LqDA2TynvhKPGlRNBuaVcb6_hXfNhdPRzE/edit) ([light HTML link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRkIfCk6z95RRPiYuRKM0C_8PzmKPAyGW3dK6NWsRHFiAAo-M9-X3RIcR47-pa8Eyc5mVj8Uniz_qOa/pubhtml)) for converting between `netstat` and `ss` arguments. It's too big to include and update it here.

[image: google doc screenshot]

The short version of difference between short arguments is:

Arguments that require attention:
`r N i g M W T v C F c A U 2 f`

Arguments that are safe to leave as is:
`h V l a n Z s p e o 4 6 x t u S w`

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this post while researching netstat -> ss conversion.  Outstanding table ***but*** I wanted to point out one thing in particular... the man page description for the netstat -s command option states, "Display summary statistics for each protocol".  ss -s option in the man page states, "Print summary statistics. This option does not parse socket lists obtaining summary from various sources. It is useful when amount of sockets is so huge that parsing /proc/net/tcp is painful."  These two command options return EXTIRELY different information.

For example:

```
$ ss -s
Total: 1365 (kernel 0)
TCP:   276 (estab 163, closed 14, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 1/0), ports 0

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         0         -         -
RAW       1         1         0
UDP       24        17        7
TCP       262       246       16
INET      287       264       23
FRAG      0         0         0
```

as opposed to the netstat -s command output (truncated):

```
$ netstat -s | head -n15
Ip:
    2043673568 total packets received
    0 forwarded
    0 incoming packets discarded
    1997519606 incoming packets delivered
    1359233819 requests sent out
    53 dropped because of missing route
    22 reassemblies required
    11 packets reassembled ok
Icmp:
    38023 ICMP messages received
    7619 input ICMP message failed.
    ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 23947
        timeout in transit: 129
```

I don't know if the upstream developers of ss intend on expanding the available output from the command, but near as I can tell... ss doesn't offer *anything* equivalent to the netstat -s statistics.

/ SenseiC bows out